# How do I tell if my child is advanced at maths?

Tags: pre-schooler

My son has just turned 4, is at pre-school, and has told me this morning that one and a half plus one and a half equals three. We haven't taught him maths apart from counting, and I don't think they would have at his play-based nursery. This seems pretty advanced to me, is it, or am I just wanting to see him as particularly brainy?

Comment: Speaking from experience: One calculation doesn't make him gifted. This is *way* too little information for an estimation. Keep observing.

Comment: See if he can actually do fraction math or if some other kid just taught him to say that. Kids can repeat very smart sounding things they heard without understanding what they mean.

Comment: @Erik, nice try, but a gifted child might  simply "feel" how fractions etc. work without being able to understand a math problem in formal language or being able to explain. Some just "process" numbers differently. But I'm absolutely with you as far as the *might have heard that somewhere* goes.

Comment: That's why I suggested you see if he can actually do it; just give him some other fractional math problems and see what happens. If he can only solve 1.5 + 1.5 = 3 then he just heard it somewhere; if he can do many of them, he's really smart.

Comment: Thanks. I asked him some other maths questions today and he was guessing the answers with hit or miss results rather than working them out. Recently he keeps asking what's beyond the universe, and is trying to understand infinity. Again, maybe this is normal for any young kid, or maybe profound, I don't know.

Comment: Intelligence is a continuum. Whether your child reaches an arbitrary 130 IQ on an arbitrary test does not really change they way you raise or educate them. You help them where they fall short and extend them where they excel.

Comment: I've updated the title to be more specific, which removed the word "Gifted" as that always causes more friction than for example, "advanced". If you feel that the word gifted is critical, feel free to [rollback my change](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/editing), which you can do through [this link](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/posts/23085/revisions)

Comment: @dave - 130+ IQ kids **most definitely** require very different approaches to raising and educating them.

Comment: user3143 - unless you have studies that show that, that's not very useful. My IQ is quite a bit higher than that, and appear to have managed ok with normal schooling. Happy to discuss in [chat]

Answer (score 4):

1. See if he displays unusual pattern recognition skills (you can consult an expert on child development, or age-appropriate IQ tests, to see what the baseline should be, and try to challenge the child with tests raising to next levels from baseline).
2. Offer him logic puzzles. Old Martin Gardner books are a very good source, although some may be a bit beyond even gifted child at 4.

   What you're testing for is two-fold: both the ability, **and** interest. Typically, being gifted in math and having IQ correllates with enjoying and being interested in logic puzzles, and finding patterns.
3. Ask him how he arrived at an answer. Better math skills usually manifest as being able to explain your solution process, vs. rote memorization.
4. Ask him different types of math challenges and try to teach him other concepts. Does he understand more complex decimal fractions than halves? Multiplication? Division? How fast (if at all) does he grasp the ideas if he doesn't know them yet?

Some good resources, though many seem more focused on older age:

- ["Testing Your Gifted Child: A Springboard for Effective Advocacy" from Duke TIP"](https://tip.duke.edu/node/809) - this lists both approaches, AND age-appropriate tests that can be administered. Some tests are possible for 4YO
- "Creativity, Giftedness, and Talent Development in Mathematics" By Bharath Sriraman. Parts are available on Google Books
- http://www.davidsongifted.org/db/Articles_id_10514.aspx

Comment: Expertise level - I grew up as mathematically gifted child, hung around many of them (magnet type school and math olympiad training), later on taught them, and was friendly with many people who were **successful** experts in gifted math education circles (as in, they trained kids who went on to succeed in or win national level math olympiads, myself included).

Answer (score 1):

One often-overlooked thing about modern society is that even very young children are tangentially exposed to advanced intellectual concepts *way* earlier than they used to be, because people discuss them more; from TV shows like Sesame Street to Nursery, there's an expectation of knowledge at an earlier age.

[As Erik says in a comment](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/23085/gifted-or-normal#comment45577_23085), the first thing to work out is whether he's just been told this one fact, or whether he's actually grasped that this is an extensible concept. [From your comment](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/23085/gifted-or-normal#comment45592_23085), it sounds like it's the second of these. That's not necessarily "wunderkind"-style Gifted (depending on the environment you create, he may be used to listening for and remembering facts), but it's still *really good* that he's proud of knowing things and wants to discuss them with you.

If you'd like to encourage him in Maths (and who doesn't want to encourage their child?), you could demonstrate some of these concepts physically (e.g. Take three biscuits, break one in half, get him to count the number of biscuits seperately and together. Then eat the biscuits.), to let him *see* how that arbitrary fact he's proud of relates to something real, which he can then play with and extend. [This is something teaching often overlooks](http://v.cx/2010/04/feynman-brazil-education).

Comment: the real test is not if he invented it.  My 4 year old independently invented addition and multiplication, but it was an accident and she couldn't "walk any distance along that road".  Whether he saw it or thought it up is irrelevant.  The real test is 1) if he understands it (like what is 1.5+2.5 or 1.25+1.75) and 2) if he can make any growth in understanding (aka walk the road).

Comment: @EngrStudent I think we're in agreement here. I never suggested that it matters "if he invented it", but if he's grasped that "1.5 + 1.5 = 3" refers to real objects and can be applied further, or if he's just memorised the words that he's been told. Where you said "walk the road", I used "extensible concept", but they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the reason you want to know if your son has mathematical talent is to decide if you should invest into additional math education. If that is the case, I would just assume he has some talent and make the investment anyway as it will pay off in the future. Many high-paid professions today require some knowledge of advanced math or at least advanced math provides a foundation that enables one to achieve more.

We have a son who is currently 16 years old. He is a senior at the Brigham Young University majoring in applied math on two academic scholarships. He consistently scores at the top of his class on tests, and is in the top ranks in math competitions. I taught him from an early age, but he never exhibited what I would consider natural brilliance - I found many of his peers grasping the same material quicker than he was when I had a chance to present it to them. At the age of 10 he was evaluated to see if he had some natural talent with a special aptitude test and failed to make the "gifted" kid bar. How did we get this "untalented" kid to perform so well?

I do know know if there is one magic bullet that did it, but I'll share with you several points that I consider to be a contributing factor:

- We home schooled from the very beginning and thus had the opportunity to influence the development of our children more directly.
- I knew enough math to teach him all the way to Calculus III.
- We were consistent and creative. Math discussions during trips and dinner. Rewards for solving a math problem. One time I made him derive a formula for the volume of the sphere while we were running - he had to integrate in his head. Another time he had to take a simple integral in his head to get me to push him down a slope while sledding.
- We did not believe in artificial limits or age brackets for when you are supposed to learn different concepts. I would always try to see how far he could go, and sometimes he surprised me. There were some inconsistencies in his knowledge/skill at times. For example, he could take square roots, and even approximate something like `sqrt(3)` as early as 5 years old, but for the life of him could not solve something like `3x+5 = 20` until he was 7. Somehow it did not bother me. I would just take him on a tour of math more or less randomly picking a challenge and then filling in the gaps as we went along when he lacked the skill to do it.
- I am a distance runner myself, and got him into running when he was 5. He has trained consistently since. Consistent running has conditioned his brain for focus - he can grind on a hard problem for hours. This is absolutely critical for success in math and other similar disciplines.
- We live a healthy life style. My son once failed a question on an early reading evaluation test because he failed to recognize the logo of McDonalds. We never eat junk food of any kind. I believe this also contributes to the ability to focus.
- I am the kind of dad that does not easily take no for an answer.

To summarize, what I get from our experience with my oldest son is that while some measure of mathematical talent does not hurt, somebody maybe in the 25% natural ability bracket can do quite well, and things like lifestyle, training, consistency, motivation, and perseverance become more of a contributing factor of success over the course of the years. Your son probably has more natural ability than ours. If you provide a healthy growth environment for him, he will do quite well if he chooses this path.